# Re.findall returning only the first match in Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex

When a sentence in `my_file` begins with a word followed by a digit, such as "City1", **and** there is another sentence in `my_file` beginning with "City2", the following code only returns the first sentence:

```
description = re.findall("\n"+i+"[\s\,\d\(].*\.\n", my_file) #i equals 'City'
if description:
        for d in description:
            d = d.replace('\n', ' ')
            bufferlist.append(d)
            bufferlist[:] = unique( bufferlist ) #unique is a function removing duplicates from a list while keeping its order
            my_string = ' '.join(bufferlist)
            del bufferlist[:]
else:
        my_string = '0'
```

Why can't I get both the first and the second sentence in `my_string`?

**EDIT**
The problem, or a part of it, was `del bufferlist[:]`. This prevented the desired pile-up of matches in every iteration. The `bufferlist` has to be deleted after the loop.

Comment: post these sentences from file

Comment: Can you give actual sample text and the output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:^|(?<=\n))City[\s\,\d\(].*\.(?=\n|$)
```

Try this.You are consuming `\n` which might not be leaving it for others to match.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/VIXyar/1